# how to filter data in Multiple table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am planning to start an iPad app...

In my app there will be 3 UITabels connected to SQLite3. How can i connect all the 3 tables together and control the data in tables with each other?

For Example

```
IF I have 3 tables 
Tabel 1: Name;
Tabel2: Country;
Tabel3: Gender;
```

The table name displays a large data of different name. suppose if a select a name called Alex . the other name should disappear from the list and  in the Country table should list only the country name related to Alex(if there is no Alex in China, then China should not appear). the Gender table should only list Male.

In the same way if i Select USA. the other name Country table should disappear and should list only related names in name list. same thing for Gender table too.

Can any one give me some ideas or Suggestions please.

Any examples or Links are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything and stuck up anywhere ?

Comment: @Jennis: planning to start need some idea how to do it and connect that tables

Comment: simple set the delegate and datasource to self re..there's nothing like connecting sqlite to tables ..its not oracle ..see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can implement such behavior manually by using the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, this seems like the perfect example to use `CoreData` instead of manually building complex models.

CoreData is a technology developed by apple to simplify the creation of apps that rely on such relatively simple data relationships.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: :I don't have issues with database..i am worried about connecting tables

Comment: Core Data actually handles all of those connections and the logic of selecting one cell and updating the data in other elements (e.g. tables) for you. That is why I recommended it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like connecting to sqlite.you just have to create a sqlite db ..store your details and access it .If any store action is performed just send a message to classes holding the tableview to update their rows.I assume you are aware of UItableview its delegate methods , datasource etc.

```
[table reloaddata];
```

iF TABLES ARE IN SAME VIEWCONTROLLER , YOU ALREADY know that changes have been made and you can reload the tables with by extracting data from sqlite.

To make your job simple and easy yOu can use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as sqlite wrapper.

[Sqlite Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application)

[Sqlite Tutorial by Wnderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app)

you can use splitebrowser plugin for firefox to see the sqlitedb

Comment: See the tutorials i mentioned

Comment: As mentioned i am clear about dataBase.. but i want to know how to build code to connect the tables to each other, for filtering the data, as mentioned in my example of Question

Comment: no just extract only those data from table you want and use it in your tables i.e in your array for table

Comment: If you get all the data in a dictionary at one time at start in appdelegate from sqlitw and then use it to extract the data you want in your view (it will be easier and increase efficiency)...no multiple database calls.